# Moshi Custom Adapter isn't being called

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, moshi

## TL;DR:

My questions are:

**1 - How can I make an `Adapter` for the `"timestamp": 1515375392.225` to `ZonedDateTime`.**

**2 - How can I register the `List<Report>` adapter in the `moshi` object `Builder` if I need the moshi object to get this adapter, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/square/moshi#parse-json-arrays)?**

---

My JSON string has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "location": {
      "latitude": -22.967049,
      "longitude": -43.19096
    },
    "timestamp": 1515375392.225
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "location": {
      "latitude": -22.965845,
      "longitude": -43.191102
    },
    "timestamp": 1515375392.225
  },
.......
}]
```

The `timestamp` is an automatic conversion made by the `Jackson` [`JavaTimeModule`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime), it converts a `ZonedDateTime` to a `timestamp String` in the form of a decimal number representing the `seconds` and `nanoseconds` from an `Instant`.

In order to parse the JSON `timestamp String`, I made the following `Moshi` adapter:

```
public class ZonedDateTimeAdapter {
    @FromJson ZonedDateTime fromJson(String timestamp) {
        int decimalIndex = timestamp.indexOf('.');
        long seconds = Long.parseLong(timestamp.substring(0, decimalIndex));
        long nanoseconds = Long.parseLong(timestamp.substring(decimalIndex));

        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanoseconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    @ToJson String toJson(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
        return instant.getEpochSecond() + "." + instant.getNano();
    }
}
```

And then I register this adapter as:

```
Type type = Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Report.class);

Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(new ZonedDateTimeAdapter()).build();
JsonAdapter<List<Report>> reportAdapter = moshi.adapter(type);

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                       .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                       .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                       .build();
```

The problem is, when I call my webservice using `Retrofit`, I get the following `Exception`:

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: ".067000000" at $[0].timestamp

*(keep in mind the nanoseconds .067000000 here won't be the same as the JSON example that I gave before, since they called the webservice at different times).*

I tried to place a breakpoint on my `ZonedDateTimeAdapter`, but it's never being called. But it's influencing Moshi, because if I remove it from the `Moshi.Builder`, the error changes to:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize
>   abstract class org.threeten.bp.ZoneId

I also tried to change the `ZonedDateTimeAdapter` to deal with `Double` instead of `String`, but it just changes the error message to:

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: ".515376840747E9" at $[0].timestamp

So, basically, I have a bunch of changing error messages and no idea what am I doing wrong. I followed the Moshi documentation on `Custom Adapters` and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: It's not anything to do with Moshi or Retrofit. Take a look at the cause in the stacktrace to see which line is giving the NumberFormatException. It looks like you are trying to parse a Long from a floating point number.

Comment: I placed a breakpoint on my Adapter, the breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: Also, despite the JSON having a floating point number, the Moshi documentation says that Moshi will convert the Adapter input to the type that I choose: `Note that the method annotated with @FromJson does not need to take a String as an argument. Rather it can take input of any type and Moshi will first parse the JSON to an object of that type and then use the @FromJsonmethod to produce the desired final value.` and I chose a String, so I am parsing from a String.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON adapter’s `@ToJson` methods is accepting a String but the timestamp is a number. Either change this to be a number (ie. double) or pass a JsonReader instead of a String and read the number out yourself. In this case you *can* call `reader.nextString()`.

Comment: I tried to make a double, as I stated in the question, the error changes to: `com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".515376840747E9" at $[0].timestamp`

Comment: Also, the documentations says that Moshi will `parse the JSON to an object of the type `, which led me to conclude that Moshi will give me the value as a string directly from the JSON, and not a number.

Comment: Is it possible that Moshi doesn't handle nicely a very big Double?

Comment: I ended up using a `JsonReader`. Neither string nor double works, all of them had exceptions as I showed in my post. Numbers should be able to be automatically presented as strings, just as `JsonReader` does.